# Execute flow condition only if its status was false and then change to true

Tags: office365, power-automate, office365-apps

I have a problem with a flow in which I would like an email to be sent if the following condition is met:

If the "Estado" column of type Boolean previously had a value of false and then changed to true.

I have consulted different documentation on this subject but I do not find clarity in the matter, it is here that I want only this part of the flow or this condition to be executed if the "Estado" is false and then changed to true. This is the example of what I have done so far in my flow.

[image]

I would like to know if anyone has an idea of how to perform this specific condition.

Comment: Questions ... are we saying the value change during the execution of the flow or are we saying that the value can change in another system somewhere like minutes/hours/days after it was originally set?  Because if it's the latter, then you'll need to persist the value somewhere so you can refer to it to see if it has in fact changed.

Comment: @Skin I think I was not very clear in explaining my question, I go back and present the scenario,

I would like the condition to be executed only when the "Estado" previously had as a value `false` and then it was changed to `true`

Is there something else you require that I can explain and thus better understand my question?

Comment: Where does the value come from? SharePoint? Excel? Somewhere else?

Comment: @Skin The value is from a table in SQL Server

Comment: This isn’t a PowerAutomate question as such, you ultimately need a way to version the records so you can get a before and after snapshot for comparison purposes. There’s a million ways to do that. You could architect that in SQL itself or outside in something like Azure Storage.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this so far is clearly elaborated here by Manuel Gomes:

https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/run-a-flow-when-a-sharepoint-column-is-modified/

You need to use the "When a file or item is modified" trigger coupled with the "Get changes for an item or a file [properties only]" in your flow.

The "When modified" trigger will point to the sharepoint list you are monitoring.

In the "Get changes" trigger, add TriggerWindowStartField to the Since field, and TriggerWindowEndToken to the Until field.

After these two triggers are set up, in the Condition trigger, you can then insert HasColumnChanged: [column you want to monitor] and set up your conditions accordingly.

[Has Column Changed selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW3mO.png)

Note: Versioning needs to be enabled on your sharepoint list (it is by default on Online Sharepoint lists)

[Sample flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJICY.png)